# How can I make a batch script supply a password with special characters to an external application?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, passwords

I have a batch script that supplies a username and password to a Windows Service that are required for that service to start. However I am running into breaking issues trying to supply a password that has special characters that are operators in Windows Batch.

The password I am using has special characters and cannot be easily changed to remove them. In this case the special characters / Batch operators that are used are `?` and `>`. Let's say the password is `my>passwor?d`. The password is stored in a separate secrets file that stores it as `"my>passwor?d"` with quotes in order to prevent the operators from being interpreted as such.

The password is supplied to an external service as:

`%MY_DIRECTORY%\MyService.exe -service %MY_USER% %MY_PWD%`

Here's where I run into trouble. `%MY_PWD%` by default, includes the quotation marks as part of the string. So when I supply it as is, `"my>passwor?d"` is supplied to the service, which is incorrect, causing it to fail.

When I strip the quotes so that I have `my>passwor?d`, the correct password, the `>` and `?` operators are run, and cause a breaking error when the batch script is executed.

Finally, when I escape the operators, such that `my>passwor?d` becomes `my^>passwor\?d` the script does *not* fail, but the password supplied to the service INCLUDES the escape characters, which is again wrong, causing the service to fail.

Is there any solution by which I can supply a password (or really any variable) that contains special characters without the escape characters or quotes being passed along with it?

**Update:** Thanks to the below answer, I managed to solve this with a slight addition that I wanted to note. Due to the variable being assigned in an external shared file, I could not change

`set MY_PWD="my>passwor?d"` to `set "MY_PWD=my>passwor?d"`

So I had to deal with scrubbing the quotes. My code ended up looking like:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set MY_PWD=!MY_PWD:"=!

@echo Passing Credentials
/MyService.exe -service %MY_USER% !MY_PWD!
endlocal
```

Comment: Why the ` \ ` backslash? Try `my^>passwor?d`

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php seemed to suggest that question marks needed to be escaped with backslashes.

Comment: But it's _Required only inside the regex pattern of `FINDSTR`_

Comment: Didn't even notice that, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a "general" solution you can try

```dos
set "MY_PWD=my>passwor?d"
for /f "delims= eol=" %%a in ("%MY_PWD%") do (
    %MY_DIRECTORY%\MyService.exe -service %MY_USER% %%~a
)
```

or

```dos
set "MY_PWD=my>passwor?d"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
%MY_DIRECTORY%\MyService.exe -service %MY_USER% !MY_PWD!
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks much! This solved it for me with one small tweak that I edited into my question.